# leetcode 530. In-order traversal of a binary search tree (C++17)

Tags: c++, c++17, binary-tree

Given a binary search tree, the [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-absolute-difference-in-bst/) requires calculating the minimum absolute difference between any two keys in the tree. Given the binary search property, the minimum difference must be between in-order neighbors.

I am basically a C++ beginner and this was my attempt at writing "idiomatic" and readable C++17. I am looking for feedback regarding where my code falls short in this aspect.

My solution, along with a description of the `TreeNode` struct, is as follows. The main idea is to have a textbook-looking in-order traversal along with a visitor that builds the in-order array. Kind of expected this pattern to make the in-order traversal subroutine more generic. Finally, I find the minimum difference using the build in-order array.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
    template <class Visitor>
    void inorder_traversal(TreeNode *root, Visitor visit) {
        if (root->left != nullptr) {
            inorder_traversal(root->left, visit);
        }
        visit(root->val);
        if (root->right != nullptr) {
            inorder_traversal(root->right, visit);
        }
        return;
    }
public:
    int getMinimumDifference(TreeNode* root) {
        using T = decltype(root->val);
        vector<T> inorder;
        auto visit = [&](T val) {
            inorder.push_back(val);
            return;
        };
        inorder_traversal(root, visit);
        adjacent_difference(inorder.begin(), inorder.end(), inorder.begin());
        auto cmp = [](T a, T b) {
            return abs(a) < abs(b);
        };
        return *min_element(inorder.begin()+1, inorder.end(), cmp);
    }
};
```

Optionally, is it possible to make this more performant while making few compromises on readability?

Some notes regarding the leetcode platform:

- the solution class was already given as a template.
- most standard library headers are included by default along with `using namespace std;`

Comment: Well two optimizations come to mind. 1) You don't actually need to build the `inorder` vector. This is only used to to the comparison and you only compare two adjacent numbers. So rather than add items to `inorder` just keep the last value and compare with the next value. 2) The minimum distance between nodes is going to be 1 or 0 (depending on if the tree allows duplicates). Once you have found a minim value there is no point continuing you will not find a smaller value just exit.

Comment: Using those optimizations it beats 70% of other entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use `std::invoke()` to call the visitor

`Visitor` can be anything: a regular function, a lambda, or even a [pointer to member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions). The latter cannot be called by writing `visit(root->val)`. To be able to support those, use [`std::invoke()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke); it will automatically do the right thing depending on the type of `Visitor`:

```
std::invoke(visit, root->val);
```

## Pass `visit` by reference

You are passing `Visitor` by value. The problem is that it doesn't work well if you pass in a mutable lambda. For example, what if I want the visitor to skip every other node? You could do that by writing:

```
auto visit = [&, skip = false](T val) mutable {
    if (!skip) {
        inorder.push_back(val);
    }
    skip = !skip;
};
```

But if you pass `visit` by value, then a copy is made every time `inorder_traversal()` is called recursively. So for example, in the outermost call to `inorder_traversal()` you will have:

```
void inorder_traversal(TreeNode *root, Visitor visit) {
    if (root->left != nullptr) {
        inorder_traversal(root->left, visit); // skip = false
    }
    visit(root->val); // skip = false before the call, true after it returns
    if (root->right != nullptr) {
        inorder_traversal(root->right, visit); // skip = true
    }
}
```

If you pass `visit` by reference, then you won't have that problem.

It doesn't matter for `getMinimumDifference()` of course, but it's a good excercise to make the traversal function as generic as possible.

## Pass by `const` reference or pointer where appropriate

I see you make no assumptions about `decltype(root->val)`, even though the LeetCode site says it will be an `int`. Writing more generic code is great though, but then consider that `T` might be a type that is large and expensive to copy. However, your visitor function takes a `T val` parameter, which will potentially make a copy every time it is called. That might be inefficient, and perhaps even impossible if `T` is `const`. So it's better to pass it by `const` reference:

```
auto visit = [&](const T& val) {
    …
};
```

In real life you would also pass `root` as a `const` pointer, but this was part of LeetCode's template, so then you are stuck with it being non-`const`.

## Use a single pass algorithm

You are going over all the data three times: once to make a `std::vector` out of the tree, the second time to calculate the adjacent differences, and the third time to find the minimum of the differences. However, you could write a visitor that remembers the previous value it visited, so it can calculate the difference, and then it can also check that against a running minimum value:

```
T minimum;
T previous;
bool first = true;

auto visit = [&](const T& val) {
    if (!first) {
        minimum = std::min(minimum, abs(val - previous));
    } else {
        first = false;
    }
    previous = val;
};

inorder_traversal(root, visit);
return minimum;
```

This also avoids having to allocate a `std::vector` to hold intermediate results, so you'll use a lot less memory as well.

## Make it even more generic

`T` is the type of `root->val`. However, if you subtract a `T` from a `T`, is the result also a `T`? That's not necessarily the case: consider having a tree of [`std::chrono::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)s. The difference between those has type [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). And maybe the overload of `abs()` that works on the difference type returns yet another type. So in my example above, I should actually have written:

```
decltype(abs(root->val - root->val)) minimum;
```

Also note that the return value of `getMinimumDifference()` should be of the same type as `minimum`, which you can easily do by just making it `auto`.

## Your function can return negative values

In your code, the vector `inorder` may contain negative values. While the lambda `cmp` calls `abs()`, the call to `min_element()` will still return a reference to an element in `inorder`, so it can return a negative value. My example above doesn't have this issue. You can fix your code by adding one more call to `abs()`.

## LeetCode is not idiomatic

> I am basically a C++ beginner and this was my attempt at writing "idiomatic" and readable C++17.

I know you have to conform to the template LeetCode give you in order for your submission to run there, but the problem is that this template is far from idiomatic C++. In particular, if you were not bound by those restrictions, you would:

- Not use a `class Solution`, but rather just have a stand-alone function `getMinimumAbsoluteDifference()` that would return the desired result.
- You would not use `using namespace std`. While it looks very handy, the problem is that you don't know everything that is being pulled into the global namespace. If you have multiple `using namespace` statements, it gets even harder. In header files you wouldn't use this at all, but in source files the proper thing to do is pull in only specifically what you need: `using std::vector;` `using std::adjacent_difference;` and so on. Or just write `std::`.